# Why is the simple calculation result differs in python and c++?

Tags: python, c++

I am using a simple dataset to calculate the linear regression between x and y values. I wrote the code both in python and c++. However the output differs a lot due to rounding(I believe) during the operations. The minimum runnable products:

cpp code:

```
void linear_regression1(){
    vector<int> independent;
    independent.push_back(60300);
    independent.push_back(60302);
    independent.push_back(60302);
    independent.push_back(60290);
    independent.push_back(60292);
    independent.push_back(60290);

    vector<double> dependent_mid;
    dependent_mid.push_back(143.5);
    dependent_mid.push_back(143.5);
    dependent_mid.push_back(143.5);
    dependent_mid.push_back(142.5);
    dependent_mid.push_back(142.5);
    dependent_mid.push_back(142.5);




    double sumX=0, sumX2=0, sumY=0, sumXY=0, a, b;

    int n = independent.size();



    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        sumX = sumX + independent[i];
        sumX2 = sumX2 + independent[i]*independent[i];
        sumY = sumY + dependent_mid[i];
        sumXY = sumXY + independent[i]*dependent_mid[i];
        //cout<<sumXY<<endl;
    }
    /* Calculating a and b */
    b = (n*sumXY-sumX*sumY)/(n*sumX2-sumX*sumX);
    a = (sumX2*sumY-sumX*sumXY)/(sumX2*n-sumX*sumX);

    /* Displaying value of a and b */
    cout<<"Equation of best fit is: y = "<< a <<" + "<< b<<"x";

}
```

python code:

```
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import seaborn as seabornInstance 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn import metrics
%matplotlib inline

data = {'x': [60300, 60302, 60300, 60302, 60290, 60292],
        'y_mid': [143.5, 143.5, 143.5, 143.5, 142.5, 142.5]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['x', 'y_mid'])



X = df['x']
y = df['y_mid']
sumX=0 
sumX2=0
sumY=0
sumXY=0

for i in range(len(X)):
    sumX = sumX + X[i]
    sumX2 = sumX2 + X[i]*X[i]
    sumY = sumY + y[i]
    sumXY = sumXY + X[i]*y[i]


b = (len(X)*sumXY-sumX*sumY)/(len(X)*sumX2-sumX*sumX)
a = (sumX2*sumY-sumX*sumXY)/(sumX2*len(X)-sumX*sumX)

print(a)
print(b)
```

I know that the Python result is correct.

Comment: what are the result and how do they differ? btw your input looks rather ill-conditioned, all points are almost the same point, so I wouldnt be too surprised about getting different results

Comment: Which are both output? Have you check intermediate results?

Comment: `60300*60300` overflows `int`, casting to `double` will probably fix it, e.g. `sumX2 + static_cast<double>(independent[i])*independent[i]`

Comment: Looks like your C++ versions uses 6 data points while the Python version uses 7 data points. Not surprising that the result differs then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an integer overflow issue in the code: 60'300 * 60'300 = 3'636'090'000 while usually an `int` are 4-bytes long and can hold only values in range [-2^31, 2^31-1] = [-2'147'483'648, 2'147'483'647].

Python's integer does not overflow.

Comment: You could also suggest alternatives - using `unsigned` or  (`unsigned`) `long long` should contain this number without issues.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen - there are a variety of possible fixes. Using `long long` or `double` and possibly combine it with utilization of a more stable computation of moments (what he does is fast but is numerically unstable when average is much bigger than deviation).

Comment: Note that `X` doesn't contain Python `int` but instead `numpy.int64` due to the round trip through `pandas.DataFrame`. And this *does* overflow though at much higher values.

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand. All of my variables are already defined as double, aren't they?.

Comment: @Doe `independent[i]*independent[i]` those are integers, and the result of the multiplcation is an integer